# How to find if a property name exists in json response using Groovy script

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I am trying to use Groovy script for my Json response in soapui and finding if the property exists in my response. I used If statement as below. For what ever property name i use to check it returns only true statement even though if the property not exists. I am not sure whats wrong I am doing here.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def i = 0

responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("DAY").getPropertyValue("response")
slurperresponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)

if(slurperresponse.day_details.activities.to_locans) {
     println "************************"
     res = "Crew_base found" 
} else {
     res = "Crew_base not found"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing it? maybe try checking for it's length `if (slurperresponse.day_details.activities.to_locans.size()>0)`. Don't know why it acts like that though.

Comment: @Mikelis Baltruks, I used size()>0 and still printing true statement. Actually my response doesn't have name called to_locans. Do I need to def any method. I tried using has method and getting error    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.has()

Comment: it's impossible. If it prints that `size is > 0`, then something is really wrong. :D Try printing (before the `if` statement) the element U r checking (that doesn't exist) and it's length.

Comment: and btw - where is the method called. Either you have copied just some chunks of code or it is not complete

Comment: I got the log for size as Fri Apr 22 15:24:34 EDT 2016:INFO:1

Comment: I got this code from online to write simple script to find if the property name exists in the response. even I tried assert slurperresponse.day_details.activities.to_locans!=null   if just gave result with null value and not error

Comment: okey. I got no idea actually. How about `element.toString().size()>0`?

Comment: Do you mean slurperresponse.day_details.activities.to_locans.toString().size()>0

Comment: No it didn't work. By looking at the script above do you think am i doing anything wrong like missing objects or so

Comment: well. the `def slurper = new JsonSlurper()` row is unnecessary. Apart from that it seems fine. Try printing the `slurperresponse` object in different variations, try defining new variables and check them in `if`s. I guess i am too dumb to figure this one out. :D

Comment: This is what I get wjen I print the object Fri Apr 22 15:50:46 EDT 2016:INFO:[[{from_location=WAS, craft=Conductor, departure_datetime=2016-04-26T13:02:00-04:00, end_datetime=2016-04-26T16:30:00-04:00, crew_base=NYP, ends_next_day=false, description=Unit, train_number=172, to_location=NYP, arrival_datetime=2016-04-26T16:30:00-04:00, zone=Zone 2, start_datetime=2016-04-26T12:52:00-04:00}, {from_location=NYP, craft=Engineer, crew_base=NYP, ends_next_day=false, description=Conductor, train_number=125, **to_location**=WAS}]]

Comment: okey. try printing the nonexisting element's dump. `println slurperresponse.day_details.activities.to_locans.dump()` The dump will show what the compiler think about that sucker.

Comment: For valid property name Fri Apr 22 16:01:19 EDT 2016:INFO:<java.util.ArrayList@260080 elementData=[[NYP, NYP]] size=1 modCount=1>   For invalid property name
Fri Apr 22 16:01:35 EDT 2016:INFO:<java.util.ArrayList@3e0 elementData=[[null, null]] size=1 modCount=1>

Comment: For invalid property name i am getting null value and size is still 1 may be thats the wrong

Comment: I don't know. If i was on my work laptop i'd run it myself. now i have no idea.

Comment: What's the complete json response (print the `responseContent` variable)?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa here is the responseContent value Mon Apr 25 09:46:26 EDT 2016:INFO:{day_details=[{fra_status=,  block_training_day=0, holiday_name=, activities=[{from_location=WAS, craft=Conductor, departure_datetime=2016-04-26T13:02:00-04:00, end_datetime=2016-04-26T16:30:00-04:00, crew_base=NYP, ends_next_day=false, description=Unit, train_number=172, to_location=NYP, arrival_datetime=2016-04-26T16:30:00-04:00, zone=Zone 2, start_datetime=2016-04-26T12:52:00-04:00}, {from_location=NYP, craft=Engineer,  to_location=WAS, zone=Zone 2, start_datetime=2016-04-26T17:55:00-04:00}]}]}

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a few things coming together:

1. Groovy returns a null for unknown keys
2. Groovy lets you use xpath type variable lookup, including if that goes via a nested list
3. Groovy truthy on a list is based on the list size - even if the list only contains null, if its not empty, then it evaluates to true.

Your comment above reveals the problem:

For valid property name

```
Fri Apr 22 16:01:19 EDT 2016:INFO:<java.util.ArrayList@260080 elementData=[[NYP, NYP]] size=1 modCount=1>
```

For invalid property name

```
Fri Apr 22 16:01:35 EDT 2016:INFO:<java.util.ArrayList@3e0 elementData=[[null, null]] size=1 modCount=1>
```

You see in both cases the result is a list (of lists) of two items - so always evaluates to true.

As a map, from your final comment where you print the dump of that variable, it looks like this:

```
[
        day_details: [
            [
                fra_status:'', block_training_day:0, holiday_name:'', activities:[
                    [ from_location:'WAS', craft:'Conductor', departure_datetime:'2016-04-26T13:02:00-04:00', end_datetime:'2016-04-26T16:30:00-04:00', crew_base:'NYP', ends_next_day:false, description:'Unit', train_number:172, to_location:'NYP', arrival_datetime:'2016-04-26T16:30:00-04:00', zone:'Zone 2', start_datetime:'2016-04-26T12:52:00-04:00' ], 
                    [ from_location:'NYP', craft:'Engineer', to_location:'WAS', zone:'Zone 2', start_datetime:'2016-04-26T17:55:00-04:00' ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Reading that, you will see that `day_details` and `activities` are both nested lists (hence the two lists in the response - so groovy navigates to each of the maps inside `activities` and looks for the key `to_locans` - not finding the key, it returns null, and puts those two nulls into a list.

Changing the if check to the following will work as you originally intended (that is with the assumption that you only want to ever consider the first element in each of those lists):

```
if (slurperresponse.day_details[0].activities[0].to_locans){
```